# How to run an Outlook VBA only when creating a New e-mail?

Tags: vba, outlook

I have written an Outlook VBA action to count the words in an e-mail body and place this count in the subject.  This runs fine, however I would like this to only run for new e-mails, and not fire when writing a response as a reply, reply all, or forward.

Code runs fine but runs for all types of e-mails: replies, new, forwarding and I need it to only run for new e-mail.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The `EntryID` property is blank for newly created items in Outlook.

Also you may consider handling the `Reply`, `Forward`, `ReplyAll` events of the `MailItem` class to detect cases when you shouldn't count words.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like:

```
Sub GetReplyType()
    Dim objItem As Object
    Set objItem = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    If objItem.Class = olMail Then
        Select Case objItem.Verb
            Case olReply
                MsgBox "The current item is a Reply."
            Case olReplyAll
                MsgBox "The current item is a ReplyAll."
            Case olForward
                MsgBox "The current item is a Forward."
            Case Else
                MsgBox "The current item is not a Reply, ReplyAll or Forward."
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).